# Scheduled email job in asp.net on AWS EC2

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, aws-lambda

I have an asp.net web page which retrieves some data from database and send to the subscribed customers. And I want to do it first day of every month. 
So is there anyway to call this web page every month except the windows task sheduler? My website is on AWS EC2. Can I use AWS Lambda function and cron to call this specific page every month?

Comment: Your instance is a windows instance? Can `curl` can be used to call your web page?

Comment: yes, it is windows instance. Could you explain me more about `curl`  please

Comment: Have you figure it out ?

Comment: No actually. I am stuck with Lambda function to call the web page. I had a quick look into the Lambda docs and seems it only allows to call an API not a web page itself? Am i right? not very sure. I don't have much experience in AWS. So bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Lambda function to sending a request to your site. And your site will send an subscription email to your customers.

`Cloudwatch` has a service call `Schedule Expressions`. It's do the same thing with `cron` but it has an option for you to trigger some AWS service at the time. In this case, you trigger the Lambda.

P.S. I think the CloudWatch's timezone is UTC, and you have to do calculate time different for it.

For more information : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html